# Lots of unexpected space appears under the content

Tags: html, css, markup

I just noticed that on my website I have lots of unexpected space, and I don't know where it is coming from.

Here is my web: http://freshbeer.lv/new/latvian/index.php

As I am unsure where problem comes from I can't post code (if I post all code it would be to damn long)

So if someone can suggest are that's causing a problem, I'll post code here for you.

Comment: Umm, where exactly is the unexpected space on that page? It looks fine to me. Can you post a picture where you mark the problematic areas in red? Also, don't forget to include your webbrowser. Does the problem occur with other webbrowsers, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the height:1511px from style.css line 287

See below image

[image]

Comment: Oh god, such dum mistake of typo... Thnx for help I'll accept your answer as soon as I can ;))

Answer (score 1):

This is creating pretty much space from your CSS file (style.css):

```
#slideshow-right {
    height: 1511px 
}
```

It's working fine if you simply remove the height attribute from that CSS rule.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

here is the issue, it was a TYPO only 1 ruined this

```
    #slideshow-right {
    height: 1511px 
}
```

it was supposed to be 151px only ; :)

one  suggestion **use Firebug** to such issue they detect problems easily.

hope this will help you in future also.

in-case you don't know : [what is firebug and how to use this](http://templatic.com/theme-support/tips-n-tutorials/how-to-use-firebug/)