# HTML and Styles alignment issues

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML and styling and I am facing a problem fitting contents in a given space.

Here is what the template provides:

```
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Webquest</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Task</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Evaluation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Conclusion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Credits</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Styling:

```
#header
{
background-image:url(header.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:921px;
height:72px;
}
```

In the space the webpage is only displaying Webquest, Home, Introduction, Task, Process, and Resources.

All the remaining elements(Evaluation, Conclusion and Credits) are not displayed in the space.

What should I do to correct this?

Comment: Your header probably isn't wide enough. Make it wider. It also sounds like you have overflow set to hidden on your `ul` or `header`

Comment: put a screenshot so we can suggest better..

Comment: push more code for better understanding

Comment: @Pankaj the site is not allowing to post a picture as i have less than 10 reputation :(

Comment: you can post somewhere else such as : http://imageshack.us/

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/capturekkh.jpg/

Comment: After i made the changes you guys suggested that was what it turned out.

Comment: Can you inform us the link where you get this template?

Comment: http://bryantsmith.com/template/

Comment: the template name is "the slant"

Comment: and if possible paste the whole code which you have in your ul and li, this is all about space, they are going out coz padding margin is more..

Comment: Here it is: http://bryantsmith.com/template/theslant/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The template being used](http://bryantsmith.com/template/theslant/) has a fixed width menu with a background image holding space for 5 menu items, but you want a menu with 8 items.

What can you do:

1. Use another template.
2. Have a shorter menu. Remove 3 of the 8 items, so you have 5 items, which fits the template layout without any changes.
3. Decrease the width of each menu item. This may not look so good.
4. Increase the width of the menu (and optionally of the whole theme).

For both options 3 and 4, you will need to create a new background image for the menu (substitute the **header.png** file of the #header background-image).

To decrease the width of each menu item, change the width of its `li` elements in `styles.css`:

```
#header ul li , #header ul li a, #header ul li a:visited{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:72px;
    width:133px;   /* CHANGE THE WIDTH HERE TO A SMALLER VALUE */
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

To increase the width of the whole menu, increase the width of the #header element:

```
#header
{
background-image:url(header.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:921px;    /* CHANGE THE WIDTH HERE TO A BIGGER VALUE */
height:72px;
}
```

Comment: "You don't need to change anything in the code. You will have to replace the header.png image to another one, which fits the amount of items in your menu" if he wont change width in the code the same issue will persist dont you think so??

Comment: @Pankaj: Change width is in the FIRST step (maybe you haven't seen... read again). The #header width and its image can still have the same 921px width - and it should, or it will break the nice look & feel of the whole theme.

Comment: the menu which are shown by the op is not going to fit without increasing width of the both this is what i think and might be he'll get output by doing your way but i dont find this suitable and perfect, anyways Nice answer :)

Comment: @Pankaj: look - http://tinkerbin.com/bziBMbhA - I have shortened the "h1" width too - but in fact, I am truly sharing this "tinkerbin" site with you (came to know today... very useful! ...similar to jsfiddle... did you know it?)

Comment: I liked this example of your work but don't you think that white lines which divides the background shows as separator for the menu.i checked the theme once again and found this...

Comment: Of course the blank lines divides the background. The background image needs to be substituted. This is a **fixed width** template. If you increase the width, you are creating a while new thing. I would open Gimp and create a new background, similar to the original, but with the spaces to fit the whole 8 items wanted for the menu...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8515/discussion-between-j-bruni-and-pankaj)

Comment: Guys as i do not have sufficient reputation i cannot comment in the chat.I found out another template which might be a good fit for what i am looking for.

Comment: It kind of weird you guys discussing so much about my question.

Comment: I think you people understood more than me about what i want :). Here is the new template i am using : http://bryantsmith.com/template/afarewelltocolor/ can you please tell me how can i fit all the eight in the space given?

Comment: You should join the chat room with both of us

Comment: @user1249051: it would be nice if you could join the chat... we had a nice time there... :) ...at least, the new template has 7 items out of the box... we just need to add a single one...

Comment: Surely you guys had a nice time, i went through the discussion and i am proud that my first question was discussed so much :).

Comment: thats bad you should have come with that much rep :|

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends on what result you want to achieve

```
h1
{
 margin:0;
}
#header ul
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
}
#header ul li
{
 float:left;
}
```

this jsfiddle output is according to what you have put in your question :
 http://jsfiddle.net/8fjZA/1/

so what is the issue?

this jsfiddle output is according to my answer though it is not clear what exactly you want :

http://jsfiddle.net/8fjZA/2/

**EDIT**

Your header width need to be more than right now...You are not showing the complete code so taking assumptions please reduce your margin padding between li and you are done....

you are using image as a header background which have width of 921px and if you increasing your menu, you have to increase this image as well

Comment: mark any of the answer which you found helpful so we can close this question

Comment: I think you people understood more than me about what i want :). Here is the new template i am using : http://bryantsmith.com/template/afarewelltocolor/ can you please tell me how can i fit all the eight in the space given?

Comment: its easy just reduce **#bar a margin right and margin left,** you'll get more space

Comment: @user1249051: http://imageshack.us/f/196/inlineedit.png/ - look at the bottom to have an idea on how we can use firebug to edit HTML/CSS and see the changes immediately in the page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545167/lots-of-unexpected-space-appears-under-the-content/9545233#9545233 there is a link in my answer in case you dont know what is FIREBUG :D

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one option here

1. remove the `height` attribute in css
2. use `overflow-y: auto` which will render a scrollbar if your content
   goes out of the specified boundary
3. Increase the `height` attribute to accommodate all your contents

This is the answer according to what I understood of your question

By the way I'm not sure if your facing a problem with your navigation bar. A screen shot would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

problem you are having is you fixed the height of header and div header has overflow attribute hidden. means everything that is out of header will be hidden.

there may be different solution best is keep the height of header auto, don't keep the height in header would make it auto. or. if you like to just make it visible by retaining the height of header then add attribute "overflow: visible;" to the header

Comment: is there any relation with width??? can you let us know how height is affecting those menu to come in next row??